# Are there any drawbacks to using load-grunt-tasks?

Tags: node.js, automation, gruntjs, npm

I recently came across the efficient magic of [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks), but am wondering why its utilization seems to be the exception and not the rule in most examples I have seen. If you are not familiar with this module, it does this:

> This module will read the `dependencies/devDependencies/peerDependencies` in your package.json and load grunt tasks that match the provided patterns.

For example, this mess in your Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-recess');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sizediff');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svgmin');
// and likely many, many more
```

...can be replaced with a simple:

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
```

So, is there any downside to this one-liner? If not, then why is it not the standard for registering Grunt tasks in online examples? I couldn't find anything on SO or The Googz, and am not very familiar with Node or Grunt, so any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is basically only one drawback which might outweight the advantages: Performance. If you're using watch the module loads the components every time a change is triggered. I had larger projects where the speed decrease was significant. You could circumvent the problem by using [jit-grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jit-grunt) which on the other hand is not compatible with every grunt-module (e.g. spritesmith).

Maybe less important is the speed decrease for a single load of the modules. load-grunt-tasks has index your tasks configurations first, before it can load the modules.

**Update May 2016**

As @TamasHegedus pointed out in his comment this no longer seems to be in Issue with `grunt-contrib-watch`.

Comment: You are not talking about grunt-contrib-watch, are you? Correct me if im wrong but I think the grunt-contrib-watch module doesnt need to load the modules because it does not start a new process to run the tasks

Comment: @TamasHegedus The question is quite old and referring indeed to grunt-contrib-watch, but to an older version of it. Back then there was the issue described above, but I'm not sure if this is still the case.

Comment: Wow sorry, I didn't notice this tread being so old. It showed up in the interesting tab for some reason. nevermind.

Comment: Thanks @hugo-der-hungrige, I've been using jit-grunt happily for some time, and it actually DOES work with spritesmith if you tell it the corresponding executable: `require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {sprite: 'grunt-spritesmith'})` (had the same problem with usemin)